# Neato output for Mrecord produces significant overlap

Tags: python, graphviz, neato

Given this demo graph, it renders (vaguely) well in the default engine, and awfully in Neato:

```py
import graphviz

a = [
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 18.442211], [0, 1.5577889]],
]
e = [
    [0, 7.8787879, 15.353535, 0, 0, 31.212121],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [11.392405, 0, 0, 22.025316, 46.582278, 0],
]
f = [88.607595, 12.121212, 64.646465, 37.974684, 84.97551, 67.23009]
w = [45.555556, 0, 0, 60, 150, 100]
Cuntreat = (100, 250, 80, 200, 150, 130)
Ctreat = (650, 200)
Cfresh = 1
plants = range(len(Cuntreat))
treatments = range(len(Ctreat))

graph = graphviz.Digraph(
    name='treatment_flow', format='svg', engine='neato',
    graph_attr={
        'rankdir': 'LR',
        'overlap': 'false', 'splines': 'true',
    },
)

graph.node(name='fresh', label='Freshwater')
graph.node(name='waste', label='Wastewater')
for plant in plants:
    graph.node(
        name=str(plant),
        shape='Mrecord',
        label=
        '{'
            '{'
                '<fresh_in> fresh|'
                '<untreat_in> untreated|'
                '<treat_in> treated'
            '}|'
            r'Plant \N|'
            '{'
                '<waste_out> waste|'
                '<untreat_out> untreated|'
                + '|'.join(
                    f'<treat_{treatment}_out> treatment {treatment}'
                    for treatment in treatments
                ) +
            '}'
        '}'
    )

for i, a_slice in enumerate(a):
    for j, a_row in enumerate(a_slice):
        for treatment, (contam, flow) in enumerate(zip(Ctreat, a_row)):
            if flow > 0:
                graph.edge(
                    tail_name=f'{i}:treat_{treatment}_out',
                    head_name=f'{j}:treat_in',
                    label=f'{flow:.1f} ({contam*flow:.1f})',
                )
for i, (e_row, contam) in enumerate(zip(e, Cuntreat)):
    for j, flow in enumerate(e_row):
        if flow > 0:
            graph.edge(
                tail_name=f'{i}:untreat_out',
                head_name=f'{j}:untreat_in',
                label=f'{flow:.1f} ({contam*flow:.1f})',
            )
for j, flow in enumerate(f):
    if flow > 0:
        graph.edge(
            tail_name='fresh',
            head_name=f'{j}:fresh_in',
            label=f'{flow:.1f} ({Cfresh*flow:.1f})',
        )
for i, (flow, contam) in enumerate(zip(w, Cuntreat)):
    if flow > 0:
        graph.edge(
            tail_name=f'{i}:waste_out',
            head_name='waste',
            label=f'{flow:.1f} ({contam*flow:.1f})',
        )

graph.view()
```

[image: neato garbageheap]

with output

```
digraph treatment_flow {
    graph [overlap=false rankdir=LR splines=true]
    fresh [label=Freshwater]
    waste [label=Wastewater]
    0 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    1 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    2 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    3 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    4 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    5 [label="{{<fresh_in> fresh|<untreat_in> untreated|<treat_in> treated}|Plant \N|{<waste_out> waste|<untreat_out> untreated|<treat_0_out> treatment 0|<treat_1_out> treatment 1}}" shape=Mrecord]
    1:treat_1_out -> 4:treat_in [label="18.4 (3688.4)"]
    1:treat_1_out -> 5:treat_in [label="1.6 (311.6)"]
    0:untreat_out -> 1:untreat_in [label="7.9 (787.9)"]
    0:untreat_out -> 2:untreat_in [label="15.4 (1535.4)"]
    0:untreat_out -> 5:untreat_in [label="31.2 (3121.2)"]
    2:untreat_out -> 0:untreat_in [label="11.4 (911.4)"]
    2:untreat_out -> 3:untreat_in [label="22.0 (1762.0)"]
    2:untreat_out -> 4:untreat_in [label="46.6 (3726.6)"]
    fresh -> 0:fresh_in [label="88.6 (88.6)"]
    fresh -> 1:fresh_in [label="12.1 (12.1)"]
    fresh -> 2:fresh_in [label="64.6 (64.6)"]
    fresh -> 3:fresh_in [label="38.0 (38.0)"]
    fresh -> 4:fresh_in [label="85.0 (85.0)"]
    fresh -> 5:fresh_in [label="67.2 (67.2)"]
    0:waste_out -> waste [label="45.6 (4555.6)"]
    3:waste_out -> waste [label="60.0 (12000.0)"]
    4:waste_out -> waste [label="150.0 (22500.0)"]
    5:waste_out -> waste [label="100.0 (13000.0)"]
}
```

Among the specific problems I need to fix:

- Edge heads and tails should not enter ports at nonsensical directions
- At least some effort should be made to avoid edge-node overlap
- Node placement needn't be as it's shown here. For example, moving plant 3 to the right would probably help avoid overlap.

I'm sure there isn't a magic bullet for all of these, but surely Neato should be able to do better?

Comment: Unless you think this is a python bug, could you provide the Graphviz input.  Try setting **splines**  `By default, splines is unset. How this is interpreted depends on the layout engine. For dot, the default is to draw edges as splines. For all other layouts, the default is to draw edges as line segments.`

Comment: Have you read the code? `splines` is already set as a graph attribute

Comment: Nope, I am not python literate

Comment: I think you will get more answers if you make your question title more descriptive of your problem and less emotional :)

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Perhaps so, but the volume of anonymous hate that StackOverflow offers never ceases to amaze me - even after that issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the symptom.
(I mean, it's bad, but not *as* bad.)

I'm using version 9:

```
$  brew info graphviz
==> graphviz: stable 9.0.0 (bottled), HEAD
Graph visualization software from AT&T and Bell Labs
https://graphviz.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/9.0.0 (330 files, 12.8MB) *
```

[image: water treatment]

Layout should improve a bit if we display smaller plants,
and especially if there's fewer of them.

With the `dot` layout engine,
the usual way to fix a train wreck is to mess with
[[constraint](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/constraint) = false];
sometimes in combination with an edge that *does*
impose a layout constraint but which is `[style = invis]`.

Here is one example of that.

Switch to dot.

```
 graph = graphviz.Digraph(
     name="treatment_flow",
     format="svg",
-    engine="neato",
+    engine="dot",
```

Force the rank of selected nodes.
Also, some edges won't affect rank.

```
         )
         + "}"
         "}",
     )
+graph.edge("1", "2", label="fake", style="invis")
+graph.edge("2", "3", label="fake", style="invis")
+graph.edge("4", "5", label="fake", style="invis")
 
 for i, a_slice in enumerate(a):
     for j, a_row in enumerate(a_slice):
         for treatment, (contam, flow) in enumerate(zip(Ctreat, a_row)):
             if flow > 0:
                 graph.edge(
                     tail_name=f"{i}:treat_{treatment}_out",
                     head_name=f"{j}:treat_in",
                     label=f"{flow:.1f} ({contam*flow:.1f})",
+                    constraint="false",
                 )
 for i, (e_row, contam) in enumerate(zip(e, Cuntreat)):
     for j, flow in enumerate(e_row):
         if flow > 0:
             graph.edge(
                 tail_name=f"{i}:untreat_out",
                 head_name=f"{j}:untreat_in",
                 label=f"{flow:.1f} ({contam*flow:.1f})",
+                constraint="false",
             )
```

It will still be a bit cluttered, but now one more lever
is available for shuffling the clutter around.

[image: dot treatment flow]

Comment: It's interesting, and my version isn't _far_ off at `dot - graphviz version 9.0.0 (20230911.1827)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the above image is an output of the **dot** engine with **splines=false** - not **neato**.  Note that the nodes are aligned in 3 columns (**rankdir=LR**), just as **dot** would produce.  **Neato** ignores **rankdir**.
Here is the result from the python file provided above (**neato**) engine:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand? I set `engine='neato'`, so it's definitely `neato` and not `dot`. Further, `neato` certainly does pay attention to `rankdir`, at least for the purposes of record node layout internally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of the **dot** engine.  Colored edges and labels might help.
[image]

Comment: I'm aware. As I said in the question, I've already tried with the default engine.